# Generate random number in Windows phone 8.1 SDK visual basic

Tags: vb.net, random, windows-phone-8.1

I am a student and developing a quiz type of project. And I get the problem that I can't get random numbers for the questions.

[image: This is what I have done now]

The idea is to generate a number and than pick one of the texts (1,2,3) and according to the text to have the right number as answear. Also I need it in VB

Comment: Code needs to be in the question as text.  Dont add a link to a picture of the code.  You also need to ask an actual question, not just declare your needs.

Comment: _What is your question?_

Comment: @Jinx88909 I ask how to generate a random number from 1 to 3 when I press the button.

Comment: I've provided an answer on how to generate a random number. You should provide your code as code rather than an image. Bare in mind my answer has been done on mobile so is untested. Should give you an idea of what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* what you want to do is generate a random number you can use [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> The Next(Int32, Int32) overload returns random integers that range from minValue to maxValue – 1. However, if maxValue equals minValue, the method returns minValue.

Here is some sample code:

```
Dim r As Random = New Random

'The values 1, 2 and 3 are possible.
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 4))
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 4))
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 4))
```

Comment: Well everything want good but now I get error "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Random'.

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question with the code you are having issues with and the error you are getting. That way it would benefit the community better (as long as the question is on topic etc).